# How to clear Spring Cache without Scheduled annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cache

I am caching with Spring cache.
How to clear cache without Scheduled Job?

Comment: Are you hoping that there is a parameter or setting on ‘@EnableCaching’ or ‘@Cacheable’ that would clear an internal Spring ConcurrentHashMap cache from time to time? It does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

You can always clear the  `Cache` manually.

For example, let's suppose you have a shared, distributed cache solution (e.g. *Hazelcast*, or *Redis*) and want to clear a specific, "named" cache when your Spring [Boot] application shuts down.

Then, you could do something like this:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyCachingSpringBootApplication { 

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyCachingSpringBootApplication.class, args);
  }

  private static final Set<String> namedCachesToClear = 
    new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("CacheOne", "CacheTwo"));

  @Autowired
  private final CacheManager cacheManager;

  @EventListener
  public void clearTargetCaches(ApplicationClosedEvent event) {
  

    this.cacheManager.getCacheNames().stream()
      .filter(namedCachesToClear::contains)
      .map(cacheName -> this.cacheManager.getCache(cacheName))
      .filter(Objects::nonNull)
      .forEach(Cache::clear);
  }
}
```

Of course, you can source the name of the caches you want to clear from anywhere, such as Spring Boot `application.properties`, or dynamically, if your application creates and uses caches dynamically, whatever.

The primary API's involved come from the `CacheManager` interface ([Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/CacheManager.html)) and `Cache` interface ([Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/Cache.html)) in the core *Spring Framework* [Cache Abstraction](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache).

However, a word of caution, Spring's Cache Abstraction is a SPI and facade for uniformly interfacing with and using different caching providers, such as *Hazelcast* or *Redis* (see complete list of supported caching providers in the Spring Boot [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/io.html#io.caching.provider)).

Therefore, you should exercise caution when using `Cache.clear()` ([Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/Cache.html#clear())) since this can have many important implications, depending on the caching provider in use (again, *Hazelcast*, *Redis*, other) as well as the topology you are using (embedded, client/server, multi-site) as well as other factors.

Choose caution when using `Cache.clear()`.

It would be better to set expiration and eviction policies instead, which again, vary from 1 caching provider to another.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the @CacheEvict annotation to remove entries from the cache when a specific method is called.

```
@CacheEvict(cacheNames = "myCache", key="#id")
   public void clearCacheById(Long id) {
    //...
 }
```

You can use the CacheManager interface to access the cache and clear it manually. For example, you can add the following code to a method:

```
@Autowired
private CacheManager cacheManager;

public void clearCache() {
 cacheManager.getCache("myCache"). 
     clear();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, Do you have any other solution in mind? Do you have any suggestions other than CacheEvict notation and Scheluded annotation?

Comment: @zoroglur take a look updated answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to clear cache without using schedule to automatically clear cache. You can try [caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine), you can set the cache expiration time

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfiguration {

    @Value("${application.cache.time-to-live:3600}")
    private int timeToLive;

    @Bean
    public Caffeine caffeineConfig() {
        return Caffeine.newBuilder().expireAfterWrite(timeToLive, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager(Caffeine caffeine) {
        CaffeineCacheManager caffeineCacheManager = new CaffeineCacheManager();
        caffeineCacheManager.setCaffeine(caffeine);
        return caffeineCacheManager;
    }

    @Bean("customKeyGenerator")
    public KeyGenerator keyGenerator() {
        return (target, method, params) -> StringUtils.arrayToDelimitedString(params, "-");
    }

}
```

Comment: Many caching providers (not just *Caffeine*) support Expiration Policies. Many advanced, robust caching providers, like Hazelcast, even support very sophisticated, custom and programmatical Expiration Policies, by key or by the objects stored in the cache. Also, you do not want to overlook Eviction Policies either. Eviction, Expiration, JVM heap memory tuning, setting eviction and critical heap thresholds to manage memory appropriately, are all important concerns here!